# Separating set definition

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm currently working on union-closed sets and I couldn't understand what a separating set is. I found that if *A* is a separating (union-closed) set it means that for any two elements of *A*, there exists a member-set containing exactly one of them. 
I am not sure of what I have understood. If we randomly choose any two elements of a set, there is a subset (contained in the set) that has exactly one of those two elements and not both of them at once. Is that correct?

Example:

> Let *S* be a set defined as follows: S={{1},{2},{1,2},{1,3},{1,2,3}}
>
> > I'd assume that *S* is *separating* considering the fact if I choose 2 and 3 (the two elements) I find 2 in {1,2} and 3 in {1,3}. 
> >     If {1,3} did not exist, *S* wouldn't be considered as a separating set.

Comment: In your example $2$ and $3$ are not elements of $S$. The sets $\{2\}$ and $\{3\}$ are.

Comment: @JSchoone I thought the elements of a set include the elements of the sets it contains.